# Accessing classes from arbitrary modules inside of package directly

Tags: python, oop, plugins, package

Not sure if there's a neat way of dealing with it, it just makes sense to me visually to lay out each object/class into it's own module under a common package.

For instance:

- /Settings/
- /Settings/`__init__.py`
- /Settings/`AbstractSetting.py`
- /Settings/`Float.py`
- /Settings/`String.py`

Each class inside of every module has the same name as the module and at the moment I keep doing this:

```
import Settings
mysetting = Settings.Float.Float()
```

..which is giving me these double "Float" names.

I could do, in the `__init__.py` of the package:

```
from Float import Float
```

..so that I could then do:

```
import Settings
mysetting = Settings.Float()
```

But I'd like this package to be dynamically updating to whatever modules I put inside of it. So that the next day, when I've added "Knob.py" to this package, I could do:

```
import Settings
myknob = Settings.Knob()
```

Makes sense?

But again, I haven't worked with packages before and are still trying to wrap my head around it and try and make it as easy as possible. At this point, I found it easier having all classes inside one big master module which is getting increasingly cumbersome.

Maybe packages isn't the way to go? What alternatives do I have?

Thanks a bunch.

EDIT: Main reason I want to do this is to let users write their own modules that will integrate with the rest of the application. A native "plugin" architeture, if  you will.

Each module will contain a class inherited by a superclass with default values. The app then has a browser with available modules that, when clicked, displays relevant information found under the modules attributes. Each class contained then has a similar interface with which the application can use.

I did some further reading and apparently this is not the way to go. I'd love to hear your ideas though on what the benefits/disadvantages of this approach could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many plugin systems. It is exemplified by the name of one such system `yapsy` (yet another plugin system).

You could create an object that provides necessary interface:

```
class Settings(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return load_plugin(attr)

settings = Settings()
```

In your code:

```
from settings import settings

knob = settings.Knob()
```

You can use whatever implementation you like for `load_plugin()` e.g., for the code from the question:

```
from importlib import import_module

def load_plugin(name):
    m = import_module('Settings.'+name)
    return getattr(m, name)
```

Comment: +1 Seems ***very*** "Pythonic", as in simple, flexible, & extensible.

Comment: This seems like the way to go. The key for this application (it will essentially just batch process a bunch of user-created python modules) is simplicity and I did intend on implementing a fallback in case the plugin wasn't written properly. (In such cases, it would simply import the plugin and discard or gently print any exceptions it might return)

Comment: After some further tests: Love it. Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should be aware that this is not the Python way. "One class per file" is a Java philosphy that does not apply in the Python world. We usually name modules in lowercase and stick related classes into the same file (in your example, all of the classes would go into `settings.py` or would be explicitely imported from there). But I guess the fact that you want users to provide plugins is a legitimate reason for your approach (immdbg does it the same way, I think).

So, if you really want to do this, you could put something like this into your `Settings/__init__.py`:

```
import os
import glob
import imp

for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '*.py')):
  modname = os.path.basename(f)[:-3]
  if modname.startswith('__'): continue
  mod = imp.load_source(modname, f)

  globals()[modname] = getattr(mod, modname)

  # or if you just want to import everything (even worse):
  #for name in dir(mod):
  #  if name.startswith('__'): continue
  #  globals()[name] = getattr(mod, name)
```

Can you feel how the Python developers don't want you to do this? :)

Comment: IMHO something like this is a reasonable way to implement a dynamic "plug-in" module architecture.

Comment: I totally get that it's unconventional, it did feel slightly wrong when I first tried it. :) Thanks for letting me know, I'll give this approach a go with care.

Comment: FWIW, this can be extended to to allow the importation of arbitrary things inside the modules using slightly more elaborate code in your package's `__init__.py` file, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426574/how-to-import-members-of-modules-within-a-package/14428820#14428820) to another question.

Comment: @martineau: Isn't that the part that I deliberately commented out in my answer?

Comment: @NiklasB: I suppose, but it highlights the fact that the user of the package not limited to doing a `from package import *`.

Comment: @martineau: This one is more like `from Module import Module`.