# Making something like plugin system

Tags: python

I want to make something like plugin system but can't make it working. To be specific I have some requirements.

I have main script who should search for other python scripts in ./plugins dir and load them.
This main script is searching for classes who inherits from Base using `globals()`

If I place these classes in the same main file it works very well but I can't get it worked as I want.

Is it possible to do this in Python?

I try to make some like this:

source: plugins/test.py

```
class SomeClass(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Name of plugin"
```

Main script just execute some methods on this class.

Comment: where do you want to make a plugin for?

Comment: The main script (where you search for the inheritance from Base) is highly relevant and a concise version of it (tailored to demonstrate your exact problem) should be appended to the question.

Comment: Take a look at [Yapsy: Yet Another Plugin SYstem](http://yapsy.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Also see [Writing a python plugin API/Architecture](http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/writing-a-python-plugin-api/).

Comment: You can also make your plugins a package. See [How to import members of modules within a package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426574/how-to-import-members-of-modules-within-a-package/14428820#14428820).

Answer (score 0):

You could either import the python file dynamically or use the `exec` statement (make sure to define a context to execute in, otherwise the context you use the statement in will be used). Then use `Base.__subclasses__`, assuming `Base` being a new-style class, or call a function from the imported plugin module. In the latter case, you must provide a plugin-registration mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_module

For py3 I think there is importlib but I don't know how to use that one offhand.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the modules using [imp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) -- imp.loadmodule will let you create namespace names dynamically if you need to.  Then you can use [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html).getmembers() and inspect.is_class() to find the classes in your imported module (example code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796180/python-get-list-of-all-classes-within-current-module)) to find all the clases defined there. Test those for being subclasses of your plugin.

...or, more pythonically, just use hasattr to find out if the imported classes 'quack like a duck' (ie, have the methods you expect from your plugin).

PS - I'm assuming you're asking for python 2.x. Good idea to tag the post with version # in future.