# Modular Compiler in Python

Tags: python, modular-design

I am writing a compiler in Python, using the [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply) (Python Lex-Yacc) library to 'compile' the compiler. The compiler has to go through a lot of rules (the 
number of just the core rules is eventually going to be a little less than a hundred, and they can be extended). So to keep the different types of rules separate, I made many Python modules in a single `modules` directory.

To include all the rules, I don't have to include the modules in this directory, but I have to include the rules (implemented as Python functions) into **the current namespace**. Once they simply exist there, the compiler's input will be properly tokenized, parsed, etc.

Here's what I've read about and tried:

- using `__import__`, `getattr`, and `sys.modules` (very raw and in general not preferred)
- the `importlib` library (how do I get everything *inside* the module?)
- a lot of fiddling with `__init__.py` and just trying to `from modules import *` which will import everything in the modules as well

But none of these seem entirely satisfactory to me. I can't do precisely what I want to do with any of them. So my question is: how can I import some of the attributes of a Python module in a subdirectory into the running namespace of a top-level module?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: I think the technique used in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426574/how-to-import-members-of-modules-within-a-package/14428820#14428820) might be helpful. As shown, you can implement almost any sort of "rules" you wish regarding what gets imported into the namespace.

Comment: @martineau: Thanks! It's a nice way to do it for a relatively small number of modules and names, but I don't think it compares with plugin libraries as mentioned in Ned's answer. However, I'll be using it till  it works! :)

Comment: Not sure what "it" you're referring to in "I'll be using it till it works!"

Comment: I'll use the method in the linked answer as long as it does not give too big a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use an existing plugin library like [stevedore](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stevedore/1.0.0.0a1).  It will give you the tools to enumerate files that can be imported, and tools to import those modules.

Comment: Can you say some more about what plugin libraries and stevedore in particular do for you?