# Import all modules from a package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have setup the following structure: [Python 201: Creating Modules and Packages](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/08/python-201-creating-modules-and-packages/). 
The `mymath`package is available at that link.

When you run the code below:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('G:\MyPython\Package')
import mymath
print (mymath.add(4,5))
print (mymath.division(4, 2))
print (mymath.multiply(10, 5))
print (mymath.fibonacci(8))
print (mymath.squareroot(48))
```

Python Version: 3.4

outer `__init__.py` contents:

```
from add import add
from divide import division
from multiply import multiply
from subtract import subtract
from adv.fib import fibonacci
from adv.sqrt import squareroot
```

My goal is to call `division`,`add`,`subtract`, etc, but if I try to call the module I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:\MyPython\Package\myscript.py", line 1, in <module>
import mymath
File "G:\MyPython\Package\mymath\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from add import add
ImportError: No module named 'add'
```

Comment: Have you looked at [_How to import members of modules within a package_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426574/how-to-import-members-of-modules-within-a-package/14428820#14428820)?

Comment: yes martineau..but i am look at older version of python document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3.x has changed import resolution. You must now specify a full relative import if you want to perform a relative import.

```
from .add import add
```