# Python3 import module error

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, package, importerror

I have `mypackage` folder with empty `__init__.py` and two modules `compute.py` and `config.py`. Being in the folder that contains `mypackage` and `main.py`, I run `python main.py` which has `from mypackage.compute import myfunction` and inside the `compute.py` there is `from config import *`. The folder structure is below:

```
main.py
mypackage
    __init__.py
    compute.py (contains myfunction)
    config.py
```

Now, when I run `python main.py` everything works perfectly, whereas if I run `python3 main.py`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mypackage.compute import myfunction
  File "/home/myself/Downloads/mypackage/compute.py", line 1, in <module>
    from config import *
ImportError: No module named 'config'
```

Not quite sure what could be wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import all modules from package in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093069/import-all-modules-from-package-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3.x has changed import resolution. You must now specify a full relative import if you want to perform a relative import.

```
from .config import *
```