# Importing lists from multiple files

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, import

In a little project I have following path-structure:

```
main.py
Data---
      |
      __init__.py
      Actions_2016_01.py
      Actions_2016_02.py
      Actions_2016_03.py
      ... and so on...
```

Every 'Action_date.py' file includes a list called

```
data = [something_1, something_2, ...]
```

Now I am trying get all the data-lists of the 'Action_date.py' files to a single list in the 'main.py' file.

I tried something like

```
files = os.listdir(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__name__), 'Data'))
all_data = []
for name in files:
    if name.startswith('Actions'):
        import Data.name
        all_data.extend(name.data)
```

But this doesn't work at all... I'm getting

```
ImportError: No module named 'Data.name'
```

as output.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Simply have to use the `importlib` module.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your `Data` package's `__init_.py` do the work:

```
def _import_modules():
    """ Dynamically import certain modules in the package, extract data in each
        of them, and store it in a module global named all_data.
    """
    from fnmatch import fnmatch
    import traceback
    import os
    global __all__
    __all__ = []
    global all_data
    all_data = []
    globals_, locals_ = globals(), locals()

    # dynamically import the desired package modules
    for filename in os.listdir(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__name__), 'Data')):
        # process desired python files in directory
        if fnmatch(filename, 'Actions*.py'):
            modulename = filename.split('.')[0]  # filename without extension
            package_module = '.'.join([__name__, modulename])
            try:
                module = __import__(package_module, globals_, locals_, [modulename])
            except:
                traceback.print_exc()
                raise
            all_data.extend(module.data)

    __all__.append('all_data')

_import_modules()
```

Which would allow you to do this in `main.py`:

```
import Data

print(Data.all_data)
```

This is an adaption of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428820/355230) to the question [*How to import members of modules within a package*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426574/how-to-import-members-of-modules-within-a-package)?