# I have a list of files, I want to iterate and import functions from those files, so as to work on them one by one, python

Tags: python, file, file-handling

I have a list of files, using command in python `from filename import *` , works for a single file as I am giving the exact name of the file, but if I want to use it as `from list[i] import *` to iterate over a list and importing function from files one after the another to  work on it, it doesn't work? what changes should I make so as to use it for a list of files, so that I can easily iterate?

Comment: Use `eval` to evaluate the string as a command

Comment: No. `eval` should never be suggested as a solution. http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: Only if the strings come from untrusted input, if the list is fixed then it shouldnt be a problem right?

Comment: Whatever you plan to do with that, please remember what the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) says about imports: "Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools. "

Comment: @NickA If you are going to try to justify using `eval`, then you should really think over your design approach. Also, there is [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). There should really never be an opportunity to justify `eval`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `literal_eval` looking at it makes it seem a much safer approach, as an extra note, I have never made use of `eval` myself.

Comment: @NickA if you haven't used a language feature before, you might want to hold off on recommending it to someone until you are aware of its advantages and disadvantages. It's uninformed spouting off like this that perpetuates bad practices like the use of `eval`

Comment: I was aware of its advantages and disadvantages and depending on the software use would be happy to use it, the majority of my python work is personal and have no worry of untrusted strings as such.  I was merely stating that it as a possibility and most certainly not that it was the best option. It the work being done here is for personal use then there is no reason not to use `eval`.

Comment: What kind of work are you planning to do on each of these modules? When you execute `from <file> import *`, you add all the objects from the module into your local namespace. This doesn't give you any easy way to identify which elements came from each module. It would be cleaner to use `import <file>` and then do something with `dir(<file>)` (or use `module = __import__('<file>')` or `module = import_module('<file>')` and then access its components via something like `dir(module)` or `inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isfunction)`).

Comment: Sounds to me like what you're trying to do is very similar to auto-importing all the sub-modules in a package. For that reason I suggest you look at [_How to import members of modules within a package_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426574/how-to-import-members-of-modules-within-a-package).

Answer (score 3):

Use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) for that:

```
from importlib import import_module

module_list = [import_module("test.mod{}".format(i)) for i in range(20)]

# OR

module_list = []
for i in range(20):
    module_list.append(import_module("test.mod{}".format(i)))
```

As stated by the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__), **do not use internal things such as `__import__`**.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for dynamic imports, you're looking for the `__import__` function.

```
for modl in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'bat',):
    __import__('parent.' + modl)
```