# Import all modules from a directory into an array

Tags: python

Behold my directory structure

```
exchange.py
exchanges/
    kraken.py
    gemini.py
    bitfinex.py
```

Now in `exchange.py` I'd like to *dynamically* load all modules from the exchanges folder so that I can iterate over them and instantiate the classes within programmatically. Pseudocode:

```
exchanges = load_modules('exchanges')
for module in exchanges:
   config = module.CONFIG # a global
   for class in module:
        loaded_classes.append(module.class) # add each class in each module to a list
```

Goal is to allow any contributor to create a class that inherits from `exchange.py`, put it into the `exchanges` folder and the app will automatically load it and its configuration.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428820/1961574) which uses the os module to load all files in a directory but this seems unreasonably hacky to me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `__init__.py` to `exchanges` folder make it as a python package

```
import sys
sys.path(path_to_modules_directory)
```

By doing so you can import all modules by using this way

```
from exchanges import *
```

Comment: thanks, but two questions remain: 1/ I thought the adding of `__init__.py` was deprecated, and 2/ how do I then dynamically access that folder's modules' names, subclasses and globals?

Comment: Answers 1. I guess `__init__.py` is not depreciated. 2. you can use `importlib` to do your task

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `__import__` or module `importlib` for with task.
For first use should scan directory for python file. After import then with `__import__` or `importlib`. Better use `importlib`

Example

```
import os
import sys

def import_libs(path):
    sys.path.append(path)
    return [__import__(os.path.join(path, module)) for module in filter(lambda x: x and x[-3:] == ".py", os.listdir("./modules/calculate/calculate"))]

print(import_libs('exchanges'))
```

Also i have one question? Why you need do this?
I think will be better if you look at the factory design pattern.

Comment: that did not seem to work for me, but you're probably right that I should look into the factory design pattern. Not quite there yet. The goal is to let anyone create a plugin by dropping a .py file into the exchanges folder

Comment: Example how "registry" class at some container

class Registry(type):
    def registry_class(cls):
        container = cls.container
        if not container:
            return
        container.classes[cls.kind] = cls

    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        cls = super(Registry, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)
        cls.registry_class()
        return cls

Comment: Also __import__ or function in module importlib return dict like object. Object has content globals and locals of module or class list.