# Dynamically import all subclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an abstract base class with a number of derived classes. I'm trying to achieve the same behaviour that I would get by placing all the derived classes in the same file as the base class, i.e. if my classes are `Base`, `DerivedA`, `DerivedB`, `DerivedC` in the file `myclass.py` I can write in another file

```
import myclass
a = myclass.DerivedA()
b = myclass.DerivedB()
c = myclass.DerivedC()
```

but with each derived class in its own file. This has to be dynamic, i.e. such that I could e.g. delete `derived_c.py` and everything still works except that now I can no longer call `myclass.DerivedC`, or that if I add a `derived_d.py`, I could use it without touching the `__init__.py` so simply using `from derived_c import DerivedC` is not an option.

I've tried placing them all in a subdirectory and in that directory's `__init__.py` use `pkgutil.walk_packages()` to import all the files dynamically, but I can't get them to then be directly in the module's namespace, i.e. rather than `myclass.DerivedC()` I have to call `myclass.derived_c.DerivedC()` because I can't figure out how (or if it's possible) to use importlib to achieve the equivalent of a `from xyz import *` statement.

Any suggestions for how I could achieve this? Thanks!

Edit: The solutions for [Dynamic module import in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python) don't provide a method for automatically importing the classes in all modules into the namespace of the package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic module import in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/dynamic-module-import-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

I had to make something quite similar a while back, but in my case I had to dynamically create a list with all subclasses from a base class in a specific package, so in case you find it useful:

1. Create a `my_classes` package containing all files for your `Base` class and all subclasses. You should include only one class in each file.
2. Set `__all__` appropriately in `__init__.py` to import all `.py` files except for `__init__.py` (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1057534/5604339)):

   ```
   from os import listdir
   from os.path import dirname, basename

   __all__ = [basename(f)[:-3] for f in listdir(dirname(__file__)) if f[-3:] == ".py" and not f.endswith("__init__.py")]
   ```
3. Import your classes using `from my_classes import *`, since our custom `__all__` adds all classes inside the `my_classes` package to the namespace.
4. However, this does not allow us direct access to the subclasses yet. You have to access them like this in your main script:

   ```
   from my_classes import *
   from my_classes.base import Base

   subclasses = Base.__subclasses__()
   ```

Now `subclasses` is a list containing all classes that derive from `Base`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately not quite what I'm looking for but may come in handy at another occasion.

Comment: @JohnO check out the question from the answer I linked, you might find something useful there

Comment: I found something in one of the questions linked in the one you linked, specifically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426574/how-to-import-members-of-modules-within-a-package/14428820#14428820. However with the caveat that both `DerivedA()` and `derived_a.DerivedA()` are now available in the package namespace. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked perfectly for what I was trying to do

Comment: This also worked perfectly for what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.6 there exists a method for [initializing subclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__init_sub#object.__init_subclass__). This is done on definition, so before all of your code gets executed. In here you can simply import the sub-class that is initialized.

*base.py*

```py
class Base:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        __import__(cls.__module__)
```

*sub1.py*

```py
class Sub1(Base):
    pass
```

*sub2.py*

```py
class Sub2(Base):
    pass
```