# Import a function in every .py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

Aloha!
I want to make an import for every .py file I have like:

maincode.py

```py
import generalimports

# somecode
```

generalimports.py

```py
import math
import x
import y
# ...
```

Comment: ok. what is stopping you from doing so?

Comment: You could adapt the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428820/355230) to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea seems to work as-is. The problem is accessing these imported modules. When you have

```
import generalimports
# (in maincode.py)
```

You access the modules with:

```
generalimports.math
generalimports.x
...
```

Although this method is discouraged, a wildcard import may suit your needs.

```
from generalimports import *
# now access modules normally
math.sqrt(6)
x.y()
```