# Creating a central registry that can be loaded in a distributed way across modules

Tags: python, registry

I am trying to create a registry that I can load with name-factory_method pairs, so that client code is able to use the registry to instantiate these objects by their given names. I can get this to work if I load the registry with pairs within the registry module.

However, I cannot seem to get the registry loaded if I distribute the loading among other modules (e.g. with the factory methods). I would prefer the latter option, as then the registry module doesn't have to be aware of all the potential factory methods. But I can't seem to get this to work.

I have created a simple three module version that works and then one that fails below:

**Working version**

registry.py

```
registry = {}

def register_thing(description, thingmaker):
    registry[description] = thingmaker

def get_thing(description, *args, **kwargs):
    thingmaker = registry[description]
    return thingmaker(*args, **kwargs)

def show_things():
    return registry.keys()

from things import Thing1
from things import Thing2
register_thing("Thing1", Thing1)
register_thing("Thing2", Thing2)
```

things.py

```
class Thing1(object):
      def __init__(self):
          pass
      def message(self):
          return "This is a thing"

class Thing2(object):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          self.args = args
          self.kwargs = kwargs
      def message(self):
          return "This is a different thing with args %r and kwargs %r" \
             % (self.args, self.kwargs)
```

use_things.py

```
import registry

print("The things in the registry are: %r" % registry.show_things())

print("Getting a Thing1")
thing = registry.get_thing("Thing1")
print("It has message %s" % thing.message())

print("Getting a Thing2")
thing = registry.get_thing("Thing2", "kite", on_string="Mothers new gown")
print("It has message %s" % thing.message())
```

Running use_things.py gives:

```
The things in the registry are: dict_keys(['Thing1', 'Thing2'])
Getting a Thing1
It has message This is a thing
Getting a Thing2
It has message This is a different thing with args ('kite',) and kwargs {'on_string': 'Mothers new gown'}
```

**Failing distributed version**
registry.py

```
registry = {}

def register_thing(description, thingmaker):
    registry[description] = thingmaker

def get_thing(description, *args, **kwargs):
    thingmaker = registry[description]
    return thingmaker(*args, **kwargs)

def show_things():
    return registry.keys()
```

things.py

```
import registry

class Thing1(object):
      def __init__(self):
          pass
      def message(self):
          return "This is a thing"

class Thing2(object):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          self.args = args
          self.kwargs = kwargs
      def message(self):
          return "This is a different thing with args %r and kwargs %r" \
             % (self.args, self.kwargs)


register.register_thing("Thing1", Thing1)
register.register_thing("Thing2", Thing2)
```

use_things.py (as before)

Now if I run use_things.py I get the following:

```
The things in the registry are: dict_keys([])
Getting a Thing1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "use_things.py", line 6, in <module>
    thing = registry.get_thing("Thing1")
  File "/home/luke/scratch/registry_example/registry.py", line 7, in get_thing
    thingmaker = registry[description]
KeyError: 'Thing1'
```

Clearly, the things.py module is never getting called and populating the registry.
If I re-add the following line at the bottom of registry.py it again works:

```
import things
```

But again this requires registry.py to be aware of the modules needed. I would prefer the registry to be populated automatically by modules below a certain directory but I cannot seem to get this to work. Can anybody help?

Comment: _I am trying to create a registry that I can load with name-factory_method pairs, so that client code is able to use the registry to instantiate these objects by their given names._ Can you expand on that? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: By factory method, I am meaning either a __init__ method or some other method that returns an object. In my example below that, I use the classes Thing1 and Thing2 and their associated __init__ methods as factory methods. The associated name is just the name I want in the registry that allows me to construct that thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is basically a "plug-in" software architecture and there are different ways of implementing one. I personally think using a Python package to do it is a good approach because it's a well-defined "pythonic" way to organize modules and the languages supports it directly, which makes doing some of the things involved a little easier.

Here's something that I think does basically everything you want. It's based on my answer to the question [How to import members of all modules within a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426574/how-to-import-members-of-all-modules-within-a-package) which requires putting all the factory scripts in a package directory, in a file hierarchy like this:

```
use_things.py              
things/                    
    __init__.py            
    thing1.py              
    thing2.py
```

The names of the package and factory scripts can easily be changed to something else if you wish.

Instead of having an explicit public registry, it just uses the package's name, `things` in this example. (There is a private `_registry` dictionary in the module, though, if you feel you really need one for some reason.)

Although the package *does* have to be explicitly imported, its `__init__.py` initialization script will import the rest of the files in the subdirectory automatically — so adding or deleting one is simply a matter of placing its script in subdirectory or removing it from there.

There's no `register_thing()` function in this implementation, because the private `_import_all_modules()` function in `__init__.py` script effectively does it automatically — but note that it "auto-registers" *everything* public in each factory module script. You can, of course, modify how this works if you want it done in a different manner. **(I have a couple of ideas if you're interested.)**

Here's the contents of each of the files as outlined above:

**`use_things.py`:**

```
import things  # Import package.

print("The things in the package are: %r" % things.show_things())

print("Getting a Thing1")
thing = things.get_thing("Thing1")
print(f"It has message {thing.message()!r}")

print("Getting a Thing2")
thing = things.get_thing("Thing2", "kite", on_string="Mothers new gown")
print(f"It has message {thing.message()!r}")
```

---

**`things/__init__.py`:**

```
def _import_all_modules():
    """ Dynamically imports all modules in this package directory. """
    import traceback
    import os
    globals_, locals_ = globals(), locals()

    registry = {}
    # Dynamically import all the package modules in this file's directory.
    for filename in os.listdir(__name__):
        # Process all python files in directory that don't start with an underscore
        # (which also prevents this module from importing itself).
        if filename[0] != '_' and filename.split('.')[-1] in ('py', 'pyw'):
            modulename = filename.split('.')[0]  # Filename sans extension.
            package_module = '.'.join([__name__, modulename])
            try:
                module = __import__(package_module, globals_, locals_, [modulename])
            except:
                traceback.print_exc()
                raise
            for name in module.__dict__:
                if not name.startswith('_'):
                    registry[name] = module.__dict__[name]

    return registry

_registry = _import_all_modules()

def get_thing(description, *args, **kwargs):
    thingmaker = _registry[description]
    return thingmaker(*args, **kwargs)

def show_things():
    return list(_registry.keys())
```

---

**`things/thing1.py`**

```
class Thing1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def message(self):
        return f'This is a {type(self).__name__}'
```

---

**`things/thing2.py`:**

```
class Thing2(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    def message(self):
        return (f"This is a different thing with args {self.args}"
                f" and kwargs {self.kwargs}")
```

---

Running `use_things.py` gives:

```
The things in the package are: ['Thing1', 'Thing2']
Getting a Thing1
It has message 'This is a Thing1'
Getting a Thing2
It has message "This is a different thing with args ('kite',) and kwargs {'on_string': 'Mothers new gown'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: Martineau has mostly answered my question and the sophisticated stuff is there. However, there was a little additional requirement that I had (in my question) but which wasn't very clear. I have used martineau's answer to create a full answer and I have shared it here for anyone wanting to see it.*

The additional requirements were that I could use any factory_method (not just a class' `__init__` function) and that I wanted to explicitly register the ones I wanted in my registry.

So here is my final version...

I use the same directory structure as Martineau:

```
use_things.py              
things/                    
    __init__.py            
    thing1.py              
    thing2.py
```

To demonstrate the other type of factory_method I have extended use_things.py by a couple of lines:

```
import things  # Import package.

print("The things in the package are: %r" % things.show_things())

print("Getting a Thing1")
thing = things.get_thing("Thing1")
print(f"It has message {thing.message()!r}")

print("Getting a Thing2")
thing = things.get_thing("Thing2", "kite", on_string="Mothers new gown")
print(f"It has message {thing.message()!r}")

print("Getting a Thing2 in a net")
thing = things.get_thing("Thing2_in_net", "kite", on_string="Mothers new gown")
print(f"It has message {thing.message()!r}")
```

Note that getting `Thing2_in_net` constructs an object of type `Thing2` but with some precomputation applied.

`thing1.py` now explicitly registers `Thing1`'s constructor (`__init__`) by declaring a tuple with a name starting `_register_<something>`. Another class `UnregisteredThing` is not registered.

```
class Thing1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def message(self):
        return f'This is a {type(self).__name__}'

_register_thing1 = ('Thing1', Thing1)

class UnregisteredThing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def message(self):
        return f'This is an unregistered thing'
```

And `thing2.py` registers two makers, one the basic constructor of Thing2 and one from a factory method:

```
class Thing2(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    def message(self):
        return (f"This is a different thing with args {self.args}"
                f" and kwargs {self.kwargs}")

def build_thing2_in_net(*args, **kwargs):
    return Thing2(*args, located='in net', **kwargs)


_register_thing2 = ('Thing2', Thing2)
_register_thing2_in_net = ('Thing2_in_net', build_thing2_in_net)
```

Finally, the `__init__.py` script, is modified to look specifically for module attributes called `_register_<something>` and it will treat these as a key/maker pair to register:

```
def build_registry():
    """ Dynamically imports all modules in this package directory. """
    import traceback
    import os
    globals_, locals_ = globals(), locals()
    registry = {}
    for filename in os.listdir(__name__):
        # Process all python files in directory that don't start with an underscore
        # (which also prevents this module from importing itself).
        if filename[0] != '_' and filename.split('.')[-1] in ('py', 'pyw'):
            modulename = filename.split('.')[0]  # Filename sans extension.
            package_module = '.'.join([__name__, modulename])
            try:
                module = __import__(
                    package_module, globals_, locals_, [modulename])
            except:
                traceback.print_exc()
                raise
            for name in module.__dict__:
                ## look for attributes of module starting in _register_
                if name.startswith('_register_'):
                    # if so assume they are key-maker pair and register them
                    key, maker = module.__dict__[name]
                    registry[key] = maker
    return registry

_registry = build_registry()

def get_thing(description, *args, **kwargs):
    thingmaker = _registry[description]
    return thingmaker(*args, **kwargs)

def show_things():
    return list(_registry.keys())
```

The resulting output shows that only registered things appear in the registry and these can be any method that constructs an object:

```
The things in the package are: ['Thing2', 'Thing2_in_net', 'Thing1']
Getting a Thing1
It has message 'This is a Thing1'
Getting a Thing2
It has message "This is a different thing with args ('kite',) and kwargs {'on_string': 'Mothers new gown'}"
Getting a Thing2 in a net
It has message "This is a different thing with args ('kite',) and kwargs {'located': 'in net', 'on_string': 'Mothers new gown'}"
```

Comment: IMO, you've simply customized my answer so it doesn't register everything in a module automatically (which I mentioned was possible and might be desireable) and are now calling it your own.

Comment: @martineau : I did acknowledge this in my post. I indicated that your answer does the sophisticated stuff. And thus I upvoted your answer. I thought it was worth expanding on this as your answer was already provided to a different question. It then seemed appropriate to indicate which answer most fully answered the question I asked. However, I seem to have fallen foul of the behavioural norms here, so I have marked your question as the accepted answer. I apologise if I have caused offence.

Comment: The behavioral norm you were breaching is one founded in the notion of fairness and giving credit were it's due. I'm glad you've apparently realized the error of your ways. Customizing my answer to better suit your needs (and posting it) is fine, because in the software engineering field code reuse is generally considered a Good Thing. In fact that's what I am effectively doing in my answer and I mentioned it — the big difference though being that I was reusing my own code and wasn't  then accepting the modified version of someone else's as the answer to my own question.