# How to import entire folder to another?

Tags: python, import, module, package

This is what my folder looks like (both folders have empty `__init__.py` file:

```
.
├── Filter
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── stp.py
└── Time
    ├── __init__.py
    └── event.py
```

In event.py I currently have (which works):

```
from Filter.stp import *
```

But I want to change it to (import entire folder since I have many more files in reality):

```
import Filter
```

How can I do that?

Comment: See [How to import members of all modules within a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426574/how-to-import-members-of-all-modules-within-a-package) It would allow you to use `from Filter import *`.

Comment: This one worked kind of. I managed to get: from Filter import *

Comment: Hard to improve on "kind of" without more information.

Answer (score 0):

Does `from Filter.stp import *` work? I believe you'll be getting a module not found error. This is because you have to have the `Filter` folder inside `Time` folder. After that you can either use `import` or `from import`.

However if you can't move the folders  across then you've to add the path (Eg. C:/.../Filter) to your `Filter` folder

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/.../Filter') # include the full path 

import stp # now you can import all the modules inside Filter
```

Comment: Correct, "from Filter.stp import *" is my current solution. Unfortunately I cannot place Filter folder inside Time folder due to complications. You know any other solution?

Comment: Thank you, but I get error: NameError 'function in stp.py' not defined

Comment: My bad, it's import stp, coz the folder Filter has already been added

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the `stp.py` and `event.py` file contain the following content:

```py
# Filter/stp.py
a = 3
b = 4

# Time/event.py
class Event:
    pass
```

You could then import these values in the respective `__init__.py` files:

```py
# Filter/__init__.py
from Filter.stp import a, b

# Time/__init__.py
from Time.event import Event
```

By using this setup, you can have a main file that looks like this:

```py
import Filter
import Time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Filter.a)  # 3
    print(Time.Event) # <class 'Time.event.Event'>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but I don't have a main file, is it possible to do without main?

Comment: Could you clarify how you're trying to call your code? Are you calling `python Time/event.py` or `python event.py`, ...?

Answer (score 0):

this may not be the best solution.

You need to import all the files in the directory in the `__init__.py` foder. but since you have many files in the directory, so you can't import them manually.

therefore we must edit `__ini__.py` programmatically:

```
import sy
path = "relative path to dir" 
files = os.listdir(path ) # i am assuming you only have the .py files you want to import
 files.pop('__init__.py')
import_file = open (path + '__init__.py', 'w+')
for f in files:
    import_file.write("import " + f.strip(".py") + "\n" )
import_file.close()
```

I can't run the code right now, so it may not be perfect.

Comment: Thanks, actually I can import them manually (it's about 10 files) so I can do it in __init__.py. But how do I do it the best possible way?