# Import all modules in a package programatically

Tags: python

I have the following structure:

```
PACKAGE/
    __init__.py
    mod1.py
    mod2.py
    ...
code.py
```

In my `code.py`, I want to import the entire PACKAGE folder:

```
import PACKAGE

# execute some functions from mod1, mod2 or ... here.
```

To ensure dynamic import, I use the following code in `__init__.py`:

```
import os
import importlib
for module in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
    if module == '__init__.py' or module[-3:] != '.py':
        continue
    importlib.import_module(module[:-3], package='PACKAGE')
del module
```

However, executing `code.py` results in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod1'`

I wonder why? By now I read several attempts to achieve what I want to do, but all of them don't work. This one here seems to be the most promising to me, but I doesn't work.

What am I not seeing here?

Also, as it came up in the comments, `from PACKAGE import *` would do the trick, but I would like to keep the import form of importing proper packages like `import PACKAGE`.

Comment: Calling `importlib.import_module()` wont bring any names into your scope, so if your idea is to "magically" be able to use any name from `mod1` or `mod2`, this is not the way to do that.

Comment: But I don't even get to that point. The error occurs during the import - and `os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))` lists all the modules in an array, which is then looped and should be imported one after the other

Comment: Are you getting the error at `import PACKAGE`?   You may want to forgo the __init__.py code and simply update the import statement in code.py to `import PACKAGE *`.  If I'm missing the point, please elaborate.

Comment: yes, I am, and trying `import PACKAGE *` gives me an `invalid synthax error` (also, I would prefer to do it without the `*`

Comment: when you call your module do you call them with PACKAGE.mode ?

Comment: I don't call anything at the moment. You see 100% of my code. All my `code.py` contains is `import PACKAGE` and the comment below. That is enough to throw the mentioned name error, since it is thrown during the import

Comment: Sorry, I should have written "from PACKAGE import *".

Comment: Well, yes. that way it would work. Should have mentioned that, this is not what I want :/ I would like to import it that I looks like a normal "standalone" package, imported like `import numpy` eg.

Comment: Probable duplicate of [How to import members of all modules within a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426574/how-to-import-members-of-all-modules-within-a-package).

Comment: I like the solution approach and the especially the accepted answer here way better, tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to append the package name ate to the beginning of the module string for this to work , otherwise it gave a `no module named <filename> ImportError`.

```
import os
import importlib
for module in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
    if module == '__init__.py' or module[-3:] != '.py':
        continue
    __import__(__name__+'.'+module[:-3], locals(), globals())
del module
```

you can use importlib

```
import os
import importlib

for module in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
    if module == '__init__.py' or module[-3:] != '.py':
        continue
    importlib.import_module("."+module[:-3], __name__ )    
del module
```

the best way is to list  all python (.py) files in the current folder and put them as **all** variable in **init**.py

```
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join
import glob
modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
```

Comment: Awesome, that works! Thanks! Could you please change the `__import__` back to `importlib.import_module` since the python docs state that the first is not meant to be used in general. Also it's confusing for some other readers later on :)