# Importing a List of Scripts Dynamically - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Say I have N python files (each with a `main` function) in a file structure like so:

```
tools \
|_ tool_1.py
|_ tool_2.py
...
|_ tool_N.py
```

Furthermore, I have a data structure like so:

```py
files = [
    {"path":"tools/tool_1.py", "alias" : "tools__tool_1"}
    {"path":"tools/tool_2.py", "alias" : "tools__tool_2"}
    ...
    {"path":"tools/tool_N.py", "alias" : "tools__tool_N"}
]
```

How can I dynamically import these files into a single python file? The number of tools will increase over time and manually adding a new line for each is not feasible.

So how can I convert this:

```py
from tools.tool_1 import main as tools__tool_1
from tools.tool_2 import main as tools__tool_2
...
from tools.tool_N import main as tools__tool_N
```

To this?

```py
for file in files:
    from file["path"] import main as file["alias"]
```

Comment: The right way to do this is with [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/importlib.html).  For example, you can do `module = importlib.import_module(name)`.  You can then do `file["alias"] = module.main`.

Comment: Can you please clarify in an example?

Comment: Sure:  `module = importlib.import_module("tool_1")`  Then do `tools__tool_1 = module.main`.  Repeat for the other modules.

Comment: I'm still hardcoding `tools__tool_1` in this example - I need to set the alias dynamically - the questions is how can I do this with `importlib` ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you can store it in a dict.  Start with:  `module = importlib.import_module("tool_1")` just as before, but then:  `file["tools__tool_1"] = module.main`.  These are Python objects, so you can manipulate them as such.

Comment: Basically your code just needs to provide the strings `"tool_1"` and `"tools__tool_1"`, then you can plug it into the above template.  The documentation link I provides can give additional details.

Comment: To add to Tom's answers, the functionality you're after requires dynamic generation of variables, which isn't considered good practice in general. Better to refactor your code such that you can work with a dict or a list in combination with `importlib`.

Comment: I  think you're implementing something with a poor design. Consider instead using some sort of plug-in system that *automatically* imports all the Python files in a folder. See [How to import members of all modules within a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426574/how-to-import-members-of-all-modules-within-a-package) for an example of what I mean.

Comment: @Daniel Ok, as you requested, I posted a fairly complete example (along with some disclaimers).  Take a look at let me know if you have any questions about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first a couple of disclaimers:  (1) Dynamically importing modules may or may not be what you actually need.  I have done so myself, but in my case I had a library with like 100 different models, and a common driver that dynamically loaded one of those models depending on the command-line options I gave it.  The main point is that I never needed more than one of them loaded at a time, so it made sense to load that one module dynamically.

And (2) I'm far from an expert at importing modules and packages, but I'm usually able to get it to do what I want.

That having been said, if you believe that dynamically importing modules is what you want, then this should work for you.  Note that I tried to create a complete example for you:

```
import importlib

files = [
    {"path" : "tools.tool_1", "name" : "tools__tool_1"},
    {"path" : "tools.tool_2", "name" : "tools__tool_2"},
    {"path" : "tools.tool_3", "name" : "tools__tool_3"}
]

module_dict = {}
main_dict = {}

for file_desc in files:
    path = file_desc["path"]
    name = file_desc["name"]

    module = importlib.import_module(path)

    module_dict[name] = module
    main_dict[name] = module.main

main_dict["tools__tool_1"]()
```

In this example, there are three modules that all reside in the directory `tools`.  The modules are `tool_1`, `tool_2`, and `tool_3`.  They are imported and stored in dictionaries under the names `tools__tool_1`, etc.  Note:  You may be able to simply use `tool_1` etc. for these names, unless you need to qualify them with `tools__` because you want to load modules from other directories into the same dictionaries.

Note that none of these imports have any effect on your global namespace.  The modules are imported as objects, and they (or their `main` functions) are stored only in the dictionaries.

In terms of what you need, I wasn't entirely sure what you wanted, so I created two dictionaries.  The first is `module_dict`, which imports the entire modules.  The second is `main_dict`, which simply contains the `main` function from each imported module, as described in the original post.
Note that each module is only imported once.  If you only need one of these dictionaries, it's simple enough to just remove the one you don't want.

Anyway, suppose you want to invoke `main` from `tools.tool_1`.  You can do this from `main_dict` as follows:

```
    main_dict["tools__tool_1"]()
```

If you want to invoke it, or any other function, from `module_dict`, you can do:

```
    module_dict["tools__tool_1"].main()
```

You can basically access everything in a module from `module_dict`, but if you only want to access `main`, then you could just have `main_dict`.

Again, there is probably more here than you need, but I wasn't entirely certain how you intended to use this.  If you only need one of the dictionaries, just get rid of the other.

Answer (score -3):

You need to call exec() function. See sample below:

```
exec('from datetime import datetime')
print(datetime.now())
```

So in your case it would be:

```
for file in files:
    exec(f'from {file["path"]} import main as {file["alias"]}')
```

Comment: Don't use `exec`.  Use `importlib`, which was specifically created to do this.

Comment: @k-war's solution is far more elegant and works as expected - whats the advantage of `importlib` over `exec`?

Comment: @Daniel Using `exec` is never elegant, and it requires you to create a command string rather than passing the arguments directly to `import_module`.  Further, you have no direct control over the namespace if you use `exec` like this.  As I said, experienced Python users use `importlib` for this.  `exec` is basically a sledgehammer that beginning Python programmers use even though better solutions are usually available.     Try to understand that `importlib` is *very easy* to use, and in fact I showed you exactly how to adapt it to your needs.  I guess you didn't understand.

Comment: A good analogy is using the deprecated `document.write` interface in javascript, as opposed to the DOM commands that replaced it.  The DOM commands let you manipulate the HTML nodes directly, as opposed to attempting to insert source code into the running program.  Similarly, the `importlib` interface in Python allows you to import modules directly, as opposed to trying to create Python source code as a string that is then dynamically executed.  That's something you want to avoid unless there's absolutely no other way to do it.  That doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: @TomKarzes - thanks for your detailed comments - happy to accept your answer as the solution to my question if you post an example